# Scrape data from a web page that is NOT well formed

Tags: php, curl, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the data from the web page. The web page can be any page. For instance I am scraping `http://www.google.com/` using `curl`. It gives so many warnings and do nothing. Warning is on line 30:

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): in
> C:\wamp\www\nbacurl\index.php

and this error repeated several times.

I heard about simplehtmldom , I downloaded it but have no clue how to use it. I have pages to parse but i can't find a way out. This is a very simple code that isn't working.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.google.com' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$contents = curl_exec ($ch);

$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($contents);
echo '<pre>' , print_r($xml) , '</pre'>;
```

Comment: I don't see you using simplehtmldom tough...Anyway, if that class fails (it's not the best out there) try [phpQuery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/)

Comment: thank you Damien, i was trying to use 'simplehtmldom' but it wasn;t working for me. so i shifted to the very basic which has 4 curl lines and couple of xml ones.

Comment: and please do me a favor, as i m new to phpQuery, wht does it actually do? its like jQuery, where make functions and call built-in functions in it?? or is it something else? Thank You

Comment: How it wasn't working? Did you read their API carefully? SimpleXMLElement is not apt to parse a (malformed) html document. As for phpQUery, why don't you just look at the page? :) Anyway, it's a DOM parser, with jQuery-like selectors. It's easy and faster than simplehtmldom, I (almost) never had problem with both

Comment: it wasn't working :) all the prerequisite were verified. curl installed, ini file checked. I am now looking into phpQuery that u suggested, and hopefully i will grab something out of it :)

Comment: A piece of advice: "it wasn't working" means nothing, you won't get any help from anybody with just that; so, if even phpQuery won't work, you know what to do, right? :) I could help you with your problems in simplehtmldom, but looks like either you didn't try anything, or you just didn't read the error messages, or you're particularly secret about them...

Comment: Its great to get advice from the senior people, for me everyone here is like teacher to me. and u r right, its a vague explanation, i will try to be more as precise as possible next time. As far as trying is concern, i have spent total of 14+ hours on scraping data, then i posted as i was totally stuck. and nothing secret, it was vague, i will try to be more elaborate next time.

Comment: Thank You Damien Pirsy, that thing is co0o0olest :) . thanks aload :)

Comment: Sorry for bothering you Damien, but i have a sort of issue regarding phpQuery, kindly have a glance at it, please :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12754520/is-it-possible-to-extract-data-from-from-more-then-100-web-pages-in-loop

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to parse it with `SimpleXMLElement`, perhaps give `DOMDocument` or other solution more geared towards HTML parsing a try.

Comment: Thank you Mike for ur time, i will look into DOMDocument and see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully nobody will vote this down for being "irrelevant", but I have used [mechanize](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/) to scrape web pages and find it very intuitive and effective.  It is easy to learn with a small api.

I just saw that you are using php not python.  Mechanize is a python/perl library so it may not be relevant here.

Comment: thank you for your time, and i a looking into the scrape that you mentioned. i hope i may find the solution in it that i was looking for.

Comment: Oops!  I was thinking it said python.  So you could use a hybrid option where you execute the python script from the php file.  Otherwise this suggestion won't be very valuable.

Comment: yes :)
i was using php, not python... but thanks for giving time to post, deeply appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try [ScriptableBrowser](http://www.lastcraft.com/browser_documentation.php) (for PHP). I personally use Mechanize with BeautifulSoup in python.

Comment: ScriptableBrowser *is* in PHP.

Comment: sorry , i perceived is wrongly. I will look into it and thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DOMDocument` and either `loadHTML` or `loadXML` with recovery enabled. The former is likely what you really want.

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($contents);

...
?>
```

See: http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.recover

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->recover = TRUE;
$doc->loadXML($contents);

...
?>
```

Comment: thank you for ur time and i have tested ur solution, but still no success, its is expecting `;` . code is 

$content = file_get_contents('http://www.google.com/');
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->recover = true;
echo '<pre>' , print_r($doc->loadHTML($content)) , '</pre>'; 

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity, line: 40 (11 times)

Comment: Use your curl code to fetch the content. And that is just a warning. Your DOM should exist. Get it with DOMDocument->saveXML(); You cannot use print_r.

Comment: it now says `Moved 302` the document was moved here. on clicking it, it redirects to the web page. how can i get `HTML/XML` from it :( ?

Comment: the return type of saveXML() is XML. but if i write this on file, it writes 1.