# Having issue in extracting data from 100 web pages in a single loop

Tags: phpquery, data-extraction

I am sort of stuck. My goal is to extract data from a website that has several hundred pages. Its a sports website and i have to extract the team names and other relevant data. So far i have been successful doing it. I ran the loop for 6-7 pages and its works perfectly well. but when i change the loop to about month(25), it retrieves incomplete data. 
For instance if the destination date is 25 October, it may stop randomly at 10-12 October. 
I am using `phpQuery` and my internet connection is 1MB. 
Kindly guide me in this matter, Thank You.

```
include 'phpQueryOneFile.php';

    $fileName = "test.txt";
    $fileHandle = fopen($fileName, 'w') or die("can't open file");


    $team2Arr[] = "" ; // Array that will store all th team2 names, in complete season
    $finalCount2 = 0 ; // counter that is maintained for the $team2Arr, including 'FFF', means this
                       // will hold the atual size of array including 'FFF'
    $totalNumberOfTeam2 = 0; // counter that will contain only the number of teams in total, 
                             // excluding the "FFF", hence the aise of team2Arr - 'FFF's = # of teams

    $team1Arr[] = "" ;  // Array that will store all th team1 names, in complete season  
    $finalCount1 = 0;   // counter that is maintained for the $team1Arr, including 'FFF', means this
                        // will hold the atual size of array including 'FFF'
    $totalNumberOfTeam1 = 0; // counter that will contain only the number of teams in total, 
                             // excluding the "FFF", hence the aise of team1Arr - 'FFF's = # of teams



    $year = '2012' ;
    $month = '10' ;
    $day = '6';

    while($day < 32)
    {
        if($day < 10)
        {
            $day = '0'.$day ; 
        }

        //$doc[] = phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML('http://www.nba.com/gameline/'.$date.'/');
        phpQuery::newDocumentFileHTML('http://www.nba.com/gameline/'.$year.$month.$day.'/');
        $time1Element[$i] = pq('.nbaFnlStatTxSm');
        $time1[$i] = $time1Element[$i]->html();
        //echo '<h2>This is The Time</h2>';
        //echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($time1[$i]) . '</pre>';
        fwrite($fileHandle, "This is The Time"."\n");
        fwrite($fileHandle, $time1[$i]."\n"."\n");

        $time2Element[$i] = pq('.nbaPreMnStatus .nbaPreStatTx');
        $time2[$i] = $time2Element[$i]->html();
        //echo '<h2>This is The Second Time that is not visible</h2>';
        //echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($time2[$i]) . '</pre>';
        fwrite($fileHandle, "This is Only Time"."\n");
        fwrite($fileHandle, $time2[$i]."\n"."\n");

        $dateElement[$i] = pq('#nbaCalSelectedDate');
        $date[$i] = $dateElement[$i]->html();
        //echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($dateElement[$i]) . '</pre>';
        //echo '<h2>The Date of the match is</h2>';
        //echo '<pre>'.$dateElement[$i].'</pre>';

        fwrite($fileHandle, "The Date of the match is (Proccessed)"."\n");
        fwrite($fileHandle, $date[$i]."\n"."\n");
        fwrite($fileHandle, "The Date of the match is (Not Proccessed)"."\n");
        fwrite($fileHandle, $dateElement[$i]."\n"."\n");



        $team2Element[$i] = pq('.nbaPreMnStatusTeamHm .nbaModTopTeamName');
        $team2[$i] = $team2Element[$i]->html();
        //echo '<h2>The Home Team is </h2>';
        //echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($team2[$i]). '</pre>';
        fwrite($fileHandle, "The Home Team is "."\n");
        fwrite($fileHandle, $team2[$i]."\n"."\n");
        //here we split the data
        //get the lenght of the string 
        echo ("The lenght of arrays is = ".strlen($team2[$i]));
        //loop till 3

        $out2 = ""; // String of lenght 3 that will pick and store 3 char and put in team2Arr
        $threeCount = 0; // counter that is represents the second dimenssion of array, 
                         // i.e character in string and number of strings are stored in array
        $teamNumber = 1; // counter that is represents that team number of particular day

        $numberOfTeams = strlen($team2[$i]) / 3; // this calutate the numberOfTeams on one day
        echo ("<br / >"."team number = ".$numberOfTeams."<br />");
        for($j=0 ; $j<$numberOfTeams ; $j++)
        {
            echo '<br />'."Team".$teamNumber." is : ";
            //here we extract pair of 3 character 
            for($k=0 ; $k<3 ; $k++)
            {
                $out2 .= $team2[$i][$threeCount]; 
                $threeCount++;
            }
            echo $out2."\n";
            $team2Arr[$finalCount2] .= $out2;
            fwrite($fileHandle, $out2."\n");
            $teamNumber++;
            $finalCount2++;
            $totalNumberOfTeam2++;
            $out2 = "";
        }
        $team2Arr[$finalCount2] = "FFF";
        $finalCount2++;


        $team1Element[$i] = pq('.nbaPreMnStatusTeamAw .nbaModTopTeamName');
        $team1[$i] = $team1Element[$i]->html();
        //echo '<h2>The Away Team is </h2>';
        //echo '<pre>' . htmlentities($team1[$i]). '</pre>';
        fwrite($fileHandle, "The Away Team is "."\n");
        fwrite($fileHandle, $team1[$i]."\n"."\n");
        echo ("\n"."The lenght of arrays is = ".strlen($team1[$i]));
        //here we split the data
        //get the lenght of the string 

        //loop till 3
        $out1 = "";      // String of lenght 3 that will pick and store 3 char and put in team1Arr
        $threeCount = 0; // REINITIALIZED counter that is represents the second dimenssion of array, 
                         // i.e character in string and number of strings are stored in array 
        $teamNumber = 1; // REINITIALIZED counter that is represents that team number of particular day

        $numberOfTeams = strlen($team1[$i]) / 3;
        echo "<br />";
        echo ("team number = ".$numberOfTeams."<br />");
        for($j=0 ; $j<$numberOfTeams ; $j++)
        {
            echo "<br />"."Team".$teamNumber." is : ";
            //here we extract pair of 3 character 
            for($k=0 ; $k<3 ; $k++)
            {
                $out1 .= $team1[$i][$threeCount]; 
                $threeCount++;
            }
            echo $out1;
            $team1Arr[$finalCount1] .= $out1;
            fwrite($fileHandle, $out1."\n");
            $teamNumber++;
            $finalCount1++;
            $totalNumberOfTeam1++;
            $out1 = "";
        }
        $team1Arr[$finalCount1] = "FFF";
        $finalCount1++;
        $day = $day + 1 ;
        $i++;

    }
    fwrite($fileHandle, $team2Arr);
    fwrite($fileHandle, $team1Arr);

    fclose($fileHandle);
    echo "<br />"."number is iteratin : ".$i;
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question. "Is it possible?" isn't a real question. I could sufficiently answer it by simply writing "Yes, it is possible to do this." or "No, it's not possible to do this" with no other information provided. Please ask an actual, specifically answerable question. The best idea would be to post the actual code you're trying to use in the loop, explain how it's not working as you expect, and ask a specific question about how to fix it.

Comment: thank you Ken for the consideration, i am new to this place, will learn alot if people like you will keep guiding me.
i have changed the title and hope its more descriptive now.

Comment: as for description, i am trying to extract data from a baseball website. The match time, Team names and couple of more things. When i run the code WITHOUT loop, it returns everything perfectly. but when i place a loop over it with around 15-20 iteration, it stops executing the code and breaks at around 7-8 iterations. i can show you the code. kindly give me few minutes

Comment: i can see your comment in notification but, its not visible here :( and in addition i am trying to find that website where we save our code and show it to the people.

Comment: You post your source code **here**, not somewhere else. Put it in your question, and format it by selecting it all and clicking the `{}` toolbar button, or by pressing Ctrl+K. All content should be here in your question, not somewhere else.

Comment: its just a random thought for me that if it isn't the problem of memory usage. Maybe the allocated memory runs out but i guess this shouldn't happen. I m using php with netbeans.